# How can i add new post on new page

Tags: posts, pages

I have set up my blog (WP 3.4) the following way: 
I had created pages in my blog, so that I have them as separate navigation items in the header (it looks like: Home, PageA, PageB, etc.).
What I want to do now is to create posts on the pages. When I create posts, there is no way to select the page, where my post should appear. The posts always appear on the "Home" page.

Actually I want to do post in specific page.
Is there any way to do it.If it is then please help me out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Posts don't "add" to particular pages. "Pages" are static by default but in combination with [Custom Page Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Custom_Page_Template) you can make them do just about anything. You'd need to create a template for each of your pages and query for your posts by category, or tag, or a custom meta field... something like that.

It is difficult to tell exactly what you are doing and why, but it sounds like you may want to [create a Custom Post Type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) for each of what you now have as a page, and then you *can* add posts to them specifically and directly. Paste some of the sample code from the Codex, like this:

```
function codex_custom_init() {
    $args = array( 'public' => true, 'label' => 'Books' );
    register_post_type( 'book', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'codex_custom_init' );
```

... into a file, save it to `wp-content/mu-plugins/somefilename.php`, and get a feel for it.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I'm not sure if I get your problem right, but... Aren't categories solution to your problem?

You can create categories: Page A, Page B, etc. and then assing posts to these categories. When you open category archive, you'll see posts assigned to this category.